# How to get all Facebook post Reactions including those who comes from shared posts

Tags: javascript, facebook, facebook-graph-api

I have the thypical implementation that let's you get the count of each reactions from a Facebook post, then i'm broadcasting those results on a Facebook Live event. 
This works perfectly, but i would like to get the full count of each reaction, including those who comes from shared posts, it usually happends when other fanpages share my post to increase the reach and people add reactions to that "shared content" and not in my post, so i can't access to those reactions.

I know this data exist because if can be seen in my post Insights (when you are the admin of the fanpage)

This is my code:

```
    function refreshCounts(postID,access_token) {
    var reactions = ['LIKE', 'LOVE', 'WOW', 'HAHA', 'SAD', 'ANGRY'].map(function (e) {
    var code = 'reactions_' + e.toLowerCase();
        return 'reactions.type(' + e + ').limit(0).summary(total_count).as(' + code + ')'
    }).join(',');

    var defaultCount = 0; 

var v1 = $('.like .counter'),
    v2 = $('.love .counter'),
    v3 = $('.sad .counter'),
    v4 = $('.haha .counter'),
    v5 = $('.angry .counter'),
    v6 = $('.shock .counter');
    var url = 'https://graph.facebook.com/v2.8/?ids=' + postID + '&fields=' + reactions + '&access_token=' + access_token;
    $.getJSON(url, function(res){
        v1.text(defaultCount + res[postID].reactions_like.summary.total_count);
        v2.text(defaultCount + res[postID].reactions_love.summary.total_count);
        v3.text(defaultCount + res[postID].reactions_sad.summary.total_count);
        v4.text(defaultCount + res[postID].reactions_haha.summary.total_count);
        v5.text(defaultCount + res[postID].reactions_angry.summary.total_count);
        v6.text(defaultCount + res[postID].reactions_wow.summary.total_count);
    });
}
```

And this is an example of a request:

```
{
  "9746288590_10154416270033591": {
  "reactions_like": {
     "data": [

     ],
     "summary": {
        "total_count": 107
     }
  },
  "reactions_love": {
     "data": [

     ],
     "summary": {
        "total_count": 22
     }
  },
  "reactions_wow": {
     "data": [

     ],
     "summary": {
        "total_count": 274
     }
  },
  "reactions_haha": {
     "data": [

     ],
     "summary": {
        "total_count": 1839
     }
  },
  "reactions_sad": {
     "data": [

     ],
     "summary": {
        "total_count": 7
     }
  },
  "reactions_angry": {
     "data": [

     ],
     "summary": {
        "total_count": 1
     }
  },
  "id": "9746288590_10154416270033591"
  }
  }
```

**Any idea? Thank you**

Comment: _“then i'm broadcasting those results on a Facebook Live event”_ – that, btw., is a use of the live video functionality that Facebook does _not_ want. (Confirmed by people working at FB in the FB developer group.)

Comment: It's just an example, i work on a TV station in Chile... we can even show those results on a screen during a TV show. Come on, let's go to the background, however, thank you